# Do 8 bit png images save memory over 32 bit images in opengl loadTexture() action?

Tags: android, memory, opengl-es, png

I've been converting my large 32 bit png images to 8 bit, as the quality doesn't change much, to see if that reduced memory usage. So far it hasn't seemed to make a dent. Is this down converting a waste since the opengl loadtexture() actions, particularly creating the bitmap, will burn the same amount of memory for 8 bit as 32 bit images anyway?

EDIT 11/6 in response to comment:

```
public void loadTexture(final int resourceId,int element)
    {
        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, options);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle[element]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);//GL_NEAREST
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
```

Comment: I take it this is using android's 'loadtexture' and this is written in Java, rather than C++ via the NDK? 
As for 32bit > 8bit, could you clarify what that means in this context? Are you converting it to an palette/index and then doing a look up in the shader, or is this 32bits per channel with some sort of floating point source? All such conversions ought to be done at load time, not at run-time. Perhaps you're calling this conversion more often than you thought? Not sure why you'd see that cyclical GC going on.